# How to use variables defined through vars_prompt of one host in another host vars?

Tags: ansible

I am having 2 plays in a playbook. One of them prompts for input from user and I want to use that variable in another play. Please suggest me how to do that

```
---
- hosts: workers
  gather_facts: false
  sudo: true
  vars_prompt:
     - name: "server_ip"
       prompt: "Enter the Server IP"
       private: no

  roles:
    - client-setup-worker

- hosts: master
  gather_facts: false
  sudo: true
  vars:
    server: "{{ hostvars['workers']['server_ip'] }}"

  roles:
    - client-setup-master
```

In the above playbook I want to use server_ip defined in workers hosts to be used in master hosts.

I am facing the error "The error was: \"hostvars['workers']\" is undefined" while doing so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am facing the error "The error was: \"hostvars['workers']\" is undefined" while doing so

That's because `workers` is evidently a group, and not a *host*, which is the only thing one will find declared in **host**vars

You'll need to grab one of the hosts at random from the `workers` group, and then extract its fact; I believe this will do that:

*update after seeing the mostly correct answer by* @VladimirBotka

```
- hosts: workers
  vars_prompt:
  # as before ...
  pre_tasks:
  - name: re-export the vars_prompt for cross playbook visibility
    set_fact:
      server_ip: '{{ server_ip }}'
  roles:
  # as before

- hosts: masters
  vars:
    server: '{{ hostvars[(groups.workers|first)].server_ip }}'
```

Comment: The problem is the **scope of vars_prompt**.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I was typing the correction while you were typing your comment :-) I'm glad I learned about that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [**scope**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=vars_prompts#scoping-variables) of variables declared in *vars_prompt* is the **play**.

Such variable may be put into the *hostvars* by *set_facts* "to use that variable in another play". For example the play below

```
- hosts: test_01
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
     - name: "server_ip"
       prompt: "Enter the Server IP"
       private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        stored_server_ip: "{{ server_ip }}"
    - debug:
        var: stored_server_ip

- hosts: test_02
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    server: "{{ hostvars.test_01.stored_server_ip }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: server
```

gives (abridged):

```
ok: [test_01] => {
    "stored_server_ip": "10.1.0.10"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "server": "10.1.0.10"
}
```

Comment: And then, in the spirit of cross-answer commentary, your answer suffers from the same problem as does the original question: it will work fine if `test_01` is a **host** but not if it is a group

Comment: It's good that you mentioned about the difference in using the host and group. Thanks :)